# how to emplace in map of(string and vector)..?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm not sure if it is possible to have a vector inside of a map container.

If yes, can I have the map with vector and vector?

**INPUT**

```
ONE 1 11 111 1111
TWO 22 2 2222
THREE 333 3333 3
```

```cpp
map<string, vector<int>> mp;
```

How to emplace the input in the above container?

```cpp
map<vector<int>, vector<int>> mp;
```

If this is possible to implement, how will you emplace elements here, and how can you access those elements?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use `std::vector<int>` as the key type for a `std::map`, especially for the input you have shown.

Comment: Q: I'm not sure if it is possible to have a vector inside of a map container.  A: Sure you can!  Q: can I have the map with vector and vector?  A: a "Map" is a key::value pair.  What's the purpose of having a "vector" as a "key"????  How would you even *USE* such a beast?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to doubt that `vector<int>` qualifies as a key (or as a value) for a map? Is there some requirement imposed by `std::map` that you think might fail? (Standard containers typically can hold any type unless there is a specific reason not to -- and any such specific reason would have to do with logical consistency, not usefulness.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first case is fairly easy to implement, eg:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void loadFile(const string &fileName, map<string, vector<int>> &mp)
{
    ifstream file(fileName.c_str());

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string key;
        if (iss >> key)
        {
            vector<int> &vec = mp[key];
            int value;
            while (iss >> value) {
                vec.push_back(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    map<string, vector<int>> mp;

    loadFile("input.txt", mp);

    // use mp as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "emplace" reference in the question is intentional, and it's asking for the syntax that `std::map::emplace` needs to have, in such a container.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that would be a 1-line change in the above code. `auto &vec = *(mp.emplace(key, vector<int>{}).first);` But this would require an empty `vector` be created every time `emplace()` is called. The original code creates a new `vector` only when the `key` doesn't exist yet. To do that with `emplace()` would require a preceding call to `mp.find()` to check for the `key`'s existence beforehand.